# A tree or a weed?

Tags: weed-control

[image]Does anyone have an idea if this is a tree or a weed? I did not plant it but have been letting it grow for about 7 months. I have not removed it because it fills an empty spot in my garden. Thank you in advance. [image]

Comment: Could be both a tree and a weed, to be honest. We could use a close-up of the leaves to help with a better ID. Also - did the leaves change color last fall? I'm assuming we're looking at new growth, so how large do the leaves normally grow?

Comment: I believe the leaves did change color and yes the growth is new. I don’t recall how big the leaves were. I used an ID app and was recognized as Chinese Elm, but I’m not familiar with the species.

Comment: Unfortunately, Chinese Elm is invasive in DC, NC, NE, NJ, VA, and WI. But I'd remove the ground-level left branches to make a single trunk tree.

Comment: @YosefBaskin is correct - in fact, it's considered a "trash tree" in the horticultural trade. They get quite large (something like 70 ft by 45 ft). I would cut it down and treat the stump with triclopyr (sold as Stump and Brush Killer), unless you feel like digging out the roots. Replace it with a shrub more suited to that site.

Comment: Thank you Yosef and Jurp for the information. I will be removing it upon hearing that it is invasive and the potential size!

Comment: I would also check with any county or state regulations on destroying invasive plant material (in your case, the cuttings/trimmings).